# Send Request to PHP file only when input reaches X characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this java script code to get data from my sql. i want to send request to php file only when the input field has 15 characters. so i used this `onkeyup="if(this.value.length>14)"`  but it didn't work. can some one please modify my java script code.. please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to this:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="15" id="name" onkeyup="check_length(this)"  />
```

And add this function into your javascript:

```
function check_length(thisObject){
     if(thisObject.value.length>14){ajaxFunction(thisObject.value)}
}
```

Edit:

> This happens when you define the functions in the head part and call
>   them, when the document is not yet initialized. Move the script part,
>   where the initialization happens and try it out.

I place you the sample code (save it in a blank html file and test it):

```
<input type="text" name="name" maxlength="15" id="name" onkeyup="check_length(this)"  />
<script>
function check_length(thisObject){
     if(thisObject.value.length>14){ajaxFunction(thisObject.value)}
}
function ajaxFunction(thisObjectValue)
{
    console.log(thisObjectValue);
    /// Do things ....
}
</script>
```

Comment: @user2373405 it's working for me. **Copy the code again** and if it still doesn't work check your console to see what error do you get.

Comment: ERROR : `[19:31:48.804] ReferenceError: ajaxFunction is not defined @ ..........:12` (12th line is `if(thisObject.value.length>14){ajaxFunction(thisObject.value)}`

Comment: @siamek sorry for trouble againg and again. please check this.. http://pastebin.com/nwidVv7c is this the complete code ? i just replaced '/// Do things ....' with my complete code. please check this ones.. http://pastebin.com/nwidVv7c (IT NOT WORKED FOR ME) please correct me